# How to transform tibble from a table of dates when x happened to table of dates with categorical data for x

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

So I have a data-set that shows the year each country joined the World Trade Organistion (WTO) and its predecessor, the General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade (1995). Something important to note is that the WTO was created in 1995 as an expansion of the GATT (created 1947) and some GATT members (e.g. angola below) did not join the WTO straight away in 1995, but waited until 1996 or later depending on the country. Some countries were also not GATT members but joined the WTO after it formed (e.g. Afghanistan below).

I would like to take my data in the format of the first tibble below and change the format to have a list of all years for each country and a categorical variable showing whether they were members of the GATT, the WTO, or neither yet. My actual data-set is much larger than this example with dates from 1948 until 2017 and many more countries so doing this manually would be awful.

for this example, just limiting dates from 1992 to 1996 and looking at the first 6 countries, basically I would like to go from this:

```
df <- data.frame(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia"), 
                 Year_joined_WTO = c(2016, 2000, 1996, 1995, 1995, 2003),
                 Year_joined_GATT = c(NA, NA, 1994, 1987, 1967, NA))
df <- as_tibble(df)

> df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Country             Year_joined_WTO Year_joined_GATT
  <fct>                         <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Afghanistan                    2016               NA
2 Albania                        2000               NA
3 Angola                         1996             1994
4 Antigua and Barbuda            1995             1987
5 Argentina                      1995             1967
6 Armenia                        2003               NA
```

to this:

```
df_intended <- data.frame(Country = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan","Afghanistan","Afghanistan","Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania","Albania","Albania","Albania","Angola", "Angola","Angola","Angola","Angola","Antigua and Barbuda","Antigua and Barbuda","Antigua and Barbuda","Antigua and Barbuda","Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Argentina","Armenia","Armenia","Armenia","Armenia","Armenia"), 
                 Year = c(1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996,1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996,1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996,1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996,1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996),
                 Member_WTO_GATT = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "GATT", "GATT", "WTO", "GATT","GATT","GATT", "WTO", "WTO", "GATT","GATT","GATT", "WTO", "WTO", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
df_intended <- as_tibble(df_intended)

print(tbl_df(df_intended), n =30)

# A tibble: 30 x 3
   Country              Year Member_WTO_GATT
   <fct>               <dbl> <fct>          
 1 Afghanistan          1992 NA             
 2 Afghanistan          1993 NA             
 3 Afghanistan          1994 NA             
 4 Afghanistan          1995 NA             
 5 Afghanistan          1996 NA             
 6 Albania              1992 NA             
 7 Albania              1993 NA             
 8 Albania              1994 NA             
 9 Albania              1995 NA             
10 Albania              1996 NA             
11 Angola               1992 NA             
12 Angola               1993 NA             
13 Angola               1994 GATT           
14 Angola               1995 GATT           
15 Angola               1996 WTO            
16 Antigua and Barbuda  1992 GATT           
17 Antigua and Barbuda  1993 GATT           
18 Antigua and Barbuda  1994 GATT           
19 Antigua and Barbuda  1995 WTO            
20 Antigua and Barbuda  1996 WTO            
21 Argentina            1992 GATT           
22 Argentina            1993 GATT           
23 Argentina            1994 GATT           
24 Argentina            1995 WTO            
25 Argentina            1996 WTO            
26 Armenia              1992 NA             
27 Armenia              1993 NA             
28 Armenia              1994 NA             
29 Armenia              1995 NA             
30 Armenia              1996 NA
```

I've tried gathering the years into one column, but the problem I encounter is how to have this within a column showing every year for each country and also showing them being members in the years after they join.

My feeble attempt:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  gather(Year_joined_WTO, Year_joined_GATT, key = member_wto_gatt, value = Year)

> df2
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   Country [6]
   Country             member_wto_gatt   Year
   <fct>               <chr>            <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan         Year_joined_WTO   2016
 2 Albania             Year_joined_WTO   2000
 3 Angola              Year_joined_WTO   1996
 4 Antigua and Barbuda Year_joined_WTO   1995
 5 Argentina           Year_joined_WTO   1995
 6 Armenia             Year_joined_WTO   2003
 7 Afghanistan         Year_joined_GATT    NA
 8 Albania             Year_joined_GATT    NA
 9 Angola              Year_joined_GATT  1994
10 Antigua and Barbuda Year_joined_GATT  1987
11 Argentina           Year_joined_GATT  1967
12 Armenia             Year_joined_GATT    NA
```

I also have tried doing some joins and merges with a list of all the dates I want (e.g.

```
years <- data.frame(Year = c(1992:1996))
years <- as_tibble(years)

> df3 <- right_join(df2, years)
Joining, by = "Year"
Warning message:
Factor `Country` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 

> df3
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Country [7]
  Country             member_wto_gatt   Year
  <fct>               <chr>            <dbl>
1 NA                  NA                1992
2 NA                  NA                1993
3 Angola              Year_joined_GATT  1994
4 Antigua and Barbuda Year_joined_WTO   1995
5 Argentina           Year_joined_WTO   1995
6 Angola              Year_joined_WTO   1996
```

)
but they were entirely unsuccessful and I cannot find any similar examples of how to do this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You can check [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) regarding why spread/gather may have issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `gather`, `complete` and `fill`. `gather` the data to long format, use `sub` to have column name with `"WTO"` and `"GATT"`, `group_by` `Country` and then `fill` the NA values with latest non-NA value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, Value, -Country) %>%
  mutate(key = sub("Year_joined_", "", key)) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  complete(Value = seq(1992, 1996)) %>%
  fill(key)
```

For your real data you can use `seq(min(Value), max(Value))` instead of hard coded years or if you already know which years every country should have you can use those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of `tidyr` (1.0.0), `gather`, `spread` would be deprecated  as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) and replaced with `pivot_longer`/`pivot_wider` and using only `tidyverse` functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Year')) %>%
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, 'Year_joined_')) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  complete(value = seq(1992, 1996)) %>% 
  fill(name)
# A tibble: 38 x 3
# Groups:   Country [6]
#   Country     value name 
#   <fct>       <dbl> <chr>
# 1 Afghanistan  1992 <NA> 
# 2 Afghanistan  1993 <NA> 
# 3 Afghanistan  1994 <NA> 
# 4 Afghanistan  1995 <NA> 
# 5 Afghanistan  1996 <NA> 
# 6 Albania      1992 <NA> 
# 7 Albania      1993 <NA> 
# 8 Albania      1994 <NA> 
# 9 Albania      1995 <NA> 
#10 Albania      1996 <NA> 
# … with 28 more rows
```